# "go mod tidy" will auto upgrade go version in go.mod?

Tags: go, go-modules

Previously the project was using `go 1.20` in `go.mod`. I've upgrade my go version to `1.21.0` on local linux machine.

When I run `go mod tidy` for the project, it upgraded `go.mod` to use `go 1.21.0` automatically.

If this is the expected behavior, is there a way to disable this behaviour, aka. don't auto update the go version in `go.mod` when run `go mod tidy`? Because others might didn't upgrade locally yet.

Comment: upon further research it might be a partially documented feature of the newer 1.21 toolchain. as mentioned here: https://go.dev/doc/toolchain *"The go get and go mod tidy commands maintain the go line to be greater than or equal to the go line of any required dependency module."*, so it could be that you have dependencies requiring 1.21 and `go mod tidy` based on that quote is going to upgrade your `go` directive. However [here](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-tidy) strangely it is not mentioned.

Comment: as for whether you can disable this behavior, the same toolchain page I linked above mentions inspecting the go env `GOTOOLCHAIN`, and set it to something other than `auto`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `go mod tidy` command does not (currently) alter the `go` directive in `go.mod` based only on the local toolchain version. It sets it based on dependencies, and does not need to track patch versions.

If you have a dependency that requires a minimum of `go1.21`, then your module *requires* `go1.21`, forcing the `go` tool to update the `go` directive in `go.mod` accordingly. It would not be of any use to have your module declare a version prior to `go1.21` when `go1.21` is actually required to build the module.

Comment: Correct, I've retracted my previous comment: the reason in my case was a dependency that requires go1.21 and this only becomes visible when running "go mod tidy -go=1.20 -compat=1.20". Maybe that's something useful to add to your answer?

Comment: `go mod tidy` in 1.21.6 *will* modify the go version in `go.mod`. I just updated a dependency and `go mod tidy` is forcing `go 1.21`.

Comment: @EthanReesor, it updates it if required, not based on the running go version (which is exactly what my answer states)